# how to get third date after from current date in sql

Tags: sql

select third date from currentdate

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Or, better yet, delete this question and store over.

Comment: can't you understand this question...this is understandable -@GordonLinoff

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Many dbms products have their own date/time functions.)

Comment: ANSI SQL answer: `select current_date + interval '3' day from ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server, try DateAdd()

```
Select cast(DateAdd(DD,3,GetDate()) as Date)
```

Returns 2016-08-14

Comment: DateAdd() is a product specific function, and the question has no dbms tagged. At least inform OP and the rest of us which dbms this is for!

Comment: @jarlh  You are correct.  I'm SQL Server centric..  Updated answer